# tikzpicture and text side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, minipage

I have several tikzpictures with an explanation or equation next to each other. As an example of it; I use the following one.

I want to obtain this:

[image]

And I obtain it when I use the document class standalone; but when I change it to the class on which I am working in, the right part goes significantly down. I have tried with making a two column table but doesn't work.

[image]

My MWE without the table is the following:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
width=7.5cm, height=8cm,
axis x line=center, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=100,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=5.5,
xmin=-7.0, xmax=7.0,
domain=-2*pi:2*pi
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
Axis Style,
xtick={
    -6.28318, -3.14159, 3.14159, 6.28318
},
xticklabels={
    $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$
}
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=0:pi] {4};
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=-3:0] {0};
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=pi:2*pi] {0};
\draw[black,fill=white] (axis cs:0,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:( -3.14159,2) 
circle(1mm) (axis cs:(3.14159,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:(6.28318,2) 
circle(1mm);
\draw[dashed]  (-6.28318,0) -- (-6.28318,5) ( -3.14159,0) -- ( -3.14159,5);
\draw[dashed] (6.28318,0) -- (6.28318,5) (3.14159,0) -- (3.14159,5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\hspace{2.725in}
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\linewidth}{X}
\[x = \epsilon [-\pi,\pi] \] \\
\[2L = 2\pi \] \\
\[ L=\pi \]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a compilation error, please do not ignore those (A closing `]`). Also, put your equations into another `minipage` environment, that should solve it

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
    width=7.5cm, height=8cm,
    axis x line=center, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    samples=100,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=5.5,
    xmin=-7.0, xmax=7.0,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi
  }}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      Axis Style,
      xtick={
        -6.28318, -3.14159, 3.14159, 6.28318
      },
      xticklabels={
        $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$
      }
      ] % << added this
      \addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=0:pi] {4};
      \addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=-3:0] {0};
      \addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=pi:2*pi] {0};
      \draw[black,fill=white] (axis cs:0,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:( -3.14159,2) 
      circle(1mm) (axis cs:(3.14159,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:(6.28318,2) 
      circle(1mm);
      \draw[dashed]  (-6.28318,0) -- (-6.28318,5) ( -3.14159,0) -- ( -3.14159,5);
      \draw[dashed] (6.28318,0) -- (6.28318,5) (3.14159,0) -- (3.14159,5);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    x \in [-\pi,\pi]  \\
    2L = 2\pi \\
    L=\pi 
  \end{align*}
  \vfill
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the vertical spacing between the equations @caverac?

Comment: Can you put `\in` instead of `=\epsilon` into your code. However +1

Comment: @user151562 Yes you can, just change the environment from `tabularx` to `align`. That should do it

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the suggestion, I thought that it was genuinely an `\epsilon` in the OP's question, but you're right, an `\in` makes much more sense

Comment: When I compile with the align* environment I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\start@align #1#2#3->\if@varwidth 
                                  \kern -\topskip \kern -\abovedisplayskip \...`

Comment: @user151562 That is interesting, it runs without a hitch on my end (1) Are you sure you copied the whole document? (2) Maybe add a `&` at the beginning of each line inside the `align` environment (3) Try `\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned} (equations) \end{aligned}\end{equation*}`

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: a proposal without minipages, tabulars etc. but just using the `pgfplots` built-in feature description.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
width=7.5cm, height=8cm,
axis x line=center, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=100,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=5.5,
xmin=-7.0, xmax=7.0,
domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
title style={at={(1,0.5)}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot1,
extra description/.code={
            \node[anchor=west,align=left] (description1) at (1.1,0.5) {$x \in [-\pi,\pi]$\\
            $2L = 2\pi$\\ $L=\pi$};
        },
Axis Style,
xtick={
    -6.28318, -3.14159, 3.14159, 6.28318
},
xticklabels={
    $-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $\pi$, $2\pi$
}]
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=0:pi] {4};
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=-3:0] {0};
\addplot[red,ultra thick,smooth,domain=pi:2*pi] {0};
\draw[black,fill=white] (axis cs:0,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:( -3.14159,2) 
circle(1mm) (axis cs:(3.14159,2) circle(1mm) (axis cs:(6.28318,2) 
circle(1mm);
\draw[dashed]  (-6.28318,0) -- (-6.28318,5) ( -3.14159,0) -- ( -3.14159,5);
\draw[dashed] (6.28318,0) -- (6.28318,5) (3.14159,0) -- (3.14159,5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you are saying you need to do several of those, I'd like to recommend group plots (section 5.8 of the pgfplots manual).